# filesystem semantics for data bases

Tags: database, filesystems

Does anyone know which file system semantics current database systems (e.g. mysql) need. I searched throughout the net and found that the BerkleyDB you can read, that every file system with POSIX semantics can be used. But I wonder if true POSIX semantics are really needed or if a subset is sufficient.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look for your answer is to search for answers to questions such as "running BerkeleyDB out of NFS". Since NFS is very common, but has relaxed semantics, these answers have surely been asked.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a complete answer, but the section 2.0 of the article ["Atomic Commit In SQLite"](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) discusses the assumptions on the underlying storage.